# Nagios: executing plugin with nrpe produces a different result from running locally

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to add an NRPE check to to monitor Puppet agent but I'm running into difficulty getting the plugin to return the correct result when executed locally.

I'm using this plugin:

when executing the script locally on the nagios client the result is correct but executing with nrpe result in a critical result.  I assume I've missed something in my config.  Other nrpe plugins are executing successfully.

I restarted nrpe.d (and checked while it was down that no nrpe pid was running)
Permissions, ownder and group for the check_puppet file are the same as my other checks

```
[root@puppet-master]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H server.addr -c check_puppet
CRITICAL: Puppet daemon not running or something wrong with process

[root@git nrpe.d]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppet
OK: Puppet agent "3.4.3" running catalogversion 1398787991, and executed at Tue 29 Apr 2014 04:13:25 PM UTC for last time
```

nagios_commands.cfg:

```
define command {
    command_line                   $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 15 -c check_puppet
    command_name                   check_nrpe_puppet
}
```

nagios_service.cfg:

```
define service {
    ## --PUPPET_NAME-- (called '_naginator_name' in the manifest)                    check_puppet
    check_command                  check_nrpe_puppet
    host_name                      server.addr
    service_description            check_puppet
    use                            generic-service
}
```

/etc/nrpe.d/nrpe-check_puppet

```
# Configuration for check_puppet (from the generic template)
command[check_puppet]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppet
```

For reference here is a working config of mine

```
define command {
    command_line                   $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 15 -c check_ram
    command_name                   check_nrpe_ram
```

}

```
define service {
    ## --PUPPET_NAME-- (called '_naginator_name' in the manifest)                check_ram_server.addr
    check_command                  check_nrpe_ram
    host_name                      server.addr
    service_description            ram
    use                            generic-service
}
```

/etc/nrpe.d/nrpe-check_ram

```
# Configuration for check_ram (from the generic template)
command[check_ram]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ram -w 10% -c 5%
```

---

Update:

I had added Nagios user to sudoers as instructed in the readme but had not tested running the check as Nagios user.  This failed because the path allowed in the sudoers list was incorrect (my plugin is in Lib64), also NRPE runs as nrpe users on my systems.

I corrected sudoers to grant nopasswed sudo for the correct folder to nrpe user and added an nrpe shell so I can test as that user (it was set to nologin)

```
bash-4.1$ whoami
nrpe
bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppet 
UNKNOWN: last_run_summary.yaml not found, not readable or incomplete
bash-4.1$ exit
exit
[root@ip-10-185-165-196 plugins]# ps auxww | grep nrpe 
nrpe     16353  0.0  0.0  41320  1364 ?        Ss   23:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c   /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
root     16814  0.0  0.0 103236   856 pts/0    S+   23:53   0:00 grep nrpe
[root@ip-10-185-165-196 plugins]#
```

On the nagios server:

```
[root@puppet-master plugins]# ./check_nrpe -H <myserver> -t 15 -c check_puppet
CRITICAL: Puppet daemon not running or something wrong with process
```

I'm running a minimal install of CentOS 6.5

I disabled requiretty with:

```
Defaults:nrpe    !requiretty
```

---

UPDATE 3:

Looks like SELinux is to blame. setenforce 0 solved the issues.
$setenforce 0

Comment: What happens when you invoke the nrpe comand from a shell?

Comment: It returns critical.  See the first code box for example.

Comment: What happens when you run the `check_puppet` command on the client **as the `nagios` user**?

Comment: There is no nagios user, all nrpe plugins are executed as root (I know, I know but I didn't set it up I inherited it and will fix but one problem at a time)

Comment: Fair enough, but could we see confirmation of that, too: perhaps the output of `ps auxww|grep nrpe` on the client?  Oh, and the output of `cat /selinux/enforce` on the client, as well?

Comment: You're saying there's a line that says "nrpe_user=root" in nrpe.cfg?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but one doesn't traditionally write a separate check_nrpe_foo command for all values of 'foo'. Traditional use is of the form: check_nrpe!foo

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source of the check_puppet script you're using?

Comment: As to the user thing.  I looked deeper into it.  nrpe is run as nrpe user and nagios is run as nagios user.  Both are added to the root group.
The pluging I'm using is: https://github.com/aswen/nagios-plugins/blob/master/check_puppet_agent

Comment: I'll provide more detailed responses later.  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Did you forget to add the line to /etc/sudoers as it shows in the comments of the script (lines 36-38)?  Remember, if this is being run as a user named `nrpe` instead of a user named `nagios` you will need to adjust the line accordingly to match the username.

Comment: As everyone else is hinting at, it's usually more helpful to test the plugins as nrpe, not as root.

Answer (score 2):

As yoonix points out, the plugin itself is pretty clear, on lines 36-38: it's just a wrapper around a core plugin, and that core plugin needs to run as root.  That's why it worked fine when you ran it as root.  The wrapper will escalate privilege via `sudo`; it's set up to execute the `sudo` itself, but you will need to provide appropriate `sudo` privileges.

Assuming your `nrpe` runs as the user `nagios`, the plugin says you'll need the following line in your `sudoers` file:

```
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/puppet,/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_puppet_agent,/bin/kill
```

(I'm not sure why it needs `/bin/kill`, but it says it does, so you'd probably better grant it or risk the plugin failing in interesting and under-documented ways.)

You don't tell us what your OS (and, if Linux, distro) is; if it were CentOS and you were using the RPMforge `nrpe`, it would run as user `nagios`.  You will need to find out what user your `nrpe` runs as, and substitute that user for the leading `nagios` in the `sudoers` line above.

Comment: Also, you might need to disable requiretty for that command, depending on your existing sudo conf (e.g., distro).